# How to submit retrieve a form from URL and submit it using PHP?

Tags: php

I found a task to access my skills. The Task is to get a form from a given URL and fill the form. The form will have 3 input as Name, email, and a count and a square, combination of "x" & "*". Fill all the fields, In the input box named `count`, I have to fill the count of "*" and then I have to submit the form. I have to use PHP only.

The form should be submitted to the same URL where I get the form. I have tried using the cURL, but it returns the form again and not the expected output.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $data = $_POST;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    $inf = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($out);
    print_r($inf);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
  }
```

After submitting the form I expect to get "Thanks for submitting." text. Instead, I get the same form as output.

Comment: That's quite amazing since `$url` is undefined.

Comment: Is there a requirement to actually read the form using php? If not, just send the request directly from curl.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Here I have posted only part of my code. If you want I'll post the entire code.

Comment: Don't bother, I think [the answer by Shivendra Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57143512/3986005) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the issue is you are sending post field value in an array instead of URL encoded, use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) or json_encode and check.

Check the below code.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $data = $_POST;

        /*** you are direct sending the array value 
        use http_build_query
         or
         $data_string = json_encode($data);
        ***/
        $data_string = http_build_query($data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string );
        $out = curl_exec($ch);
        $inf = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($out);
        print_r($inf);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do anything to forms. In that case, you should get the html form (`curl` is an option. Then parse the form to get the forms method (get/post), it's action (url), and all input names.

For that you could use something like [xpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

From there, you submit another request, by crafting the data from given information above.